# Kendo MVVM custom widget: accept object as parameter

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

When developing a custom Kendo MVVM widget, passing a simple data-bound parameter seems fine, whether in a custom binding. IE:

`<div data-bind="value: simpleParameter">This works fine</div>`

`<div data-bind="mybinding: simpleParameter">This also works fine</div>`

I notice the `css` and `events` bindings can accept objects as parameters. I really want to accept objects as parameters too, but when I try, it throws an error:

`<div data-role="mycomponent" data-bind="value: { prop: value }">This throws</div>`

`<div data-role="mycomponent" data-bind="mybinding: { prop: value }">This throws too</div>`

In the case of the custom binding, it doesn't throw until I try accessing the value. I've tried it like...

`var arg = this.bindings["mybinding"].get();`

...and other variations, but nothing seems to work. Is it possible to accept objects like `{ prop: value, prop2: value2 }` for custom Kendo UI widgets in their MVVM framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in this article, [Making Kendo UI Binders for Complex Types](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/making-kendo-ui-binders-for-complex-types).

> If you have tried to make a binder like this yourself, you have
>   probably run into issues. Kendo actually does not provide support for
>   these complex bind paths for custom binders.

Basically, Kendo UI expects your expressions to be a string representation of a  variable or function name, not a complex object. What you have to do is call `this.bindings.class.get()` multiple times to retrieve the values you need.

To get these values for the `get()` function to read, you'll create a list of key/value pairs from the complex object in the binding's `init()` constructor method. Then, in your binding's `refresh()` method, you simply iterate over this list and call `get()`.

Comment: This is definitely the answer. I've yet to try it but plan to. I think SO encourages putting more detail in answers than just a link - maybe even a brief summary - any chance you might want to do that?

Comment: thanks! and I did try it and of course it worked, though ... wow... I wish I didn't need to use kendo on this project.